# Can't get the language entity with the method _languageRepository.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=langCode)

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Please help me solve this issue ,it drivers me mad .Thank you in advance.

`Version:3.1.3 Abp ModuelZero MPA`

I need to get the language id by language name from Database.
So I  inject the Repository as below.

`private readonly IRepository<ApplicationLanguage> _languageRepository;`

Then I use the below method to get the language entity

`var lang =  _languageRepository.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name==langName);`

but the result is null .The parameter is `'zh-TW'` and I am sure it exists in database.

The below screenshots for your reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var lang =  _languageRepository.Where(x=>x.Equals(langName)).FirstOrDefault();
return lang?.Id;
```

`lang?.Id` is to handle null.